# play 1.2.5 using modules for each applicarion individual

Tags: playframework

I am using heavily the Crud-Module in different projects. I activate the module by writing "play -> crud" in the dependency yaml-file. Unfortunetately the Message.properties are all the same.

How can i install an own Module for every application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create your own module repository

```
require:
    - play
    - modules -> crud 1.0

repositories:
  - modules:
      type: local
      artifact: "c:/modules/app1/[module]-[revision]"
      contains:
          - modules -> *
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I believe CRUD module should pick up the messages file from each application conf directory. Have you try to override the CRUD messages from your application messages?